# Quick Setup of Sliders

Tags: netlogo, sliders

Firstly apologies if this has already been asked, it was difficult to search for on the forum.

I have numerous sliders on my project. I want to add some buttons to my model so that when I click button A it changes certain sliders to a set value. This will allow the user to select certain scenarios quickly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every slider is associated with a global variable, and you can set that global variable from code. If your slider is called `my-slider`, then in your code do e.g.:

```
set my-slider 5
```